# Advise on setup to use for Windows

Tags: windows, installation, clickonce

We have a a new WinForm app that we need to install at a number of clients, and update sometimes. Only requirement is .Net 4.5 and up. Its a long time since I worked with installers, but I see now most types seems to be deprecated. Windows Installer is gone, and it seems like ClickOnce is deprecated, Microsofts help files are several years old (as well as the component you can choose in the wizard). And in the forums people discourages you to use ClickOnce.

InstallShield is to expensive, and an overkill for our simple app. What are the recommended way to install applications now a days? I guess people still install apps in Windows..? :-)

Comment: The Setup project feature [is not gone](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects), ClickOnce is not deprecated, there is no point in updating help files when the feature did not require changes for many years.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Inno Setup](http://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php),

> Inno Setup is a free installer for Windows programs. First introduced in 1997, Inno
>   Setup today rivals and even surpasses many commercial installers in
>   feature set and stability.

or else another good software is,

[NSIS -Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

> NSIS is a professional open source system to create Windows installers.
>   It is designed to be as small and flexible as possible and is
>   therefore very suitable for internet distribution.